# Error indexing handleIncreaseLiquidity on a local graph-node on Token#get:decimals with message: "Value is not a BigInt"

Tags: uniswap, typescript, uniswapv3, goerli, subgraph

**Hi, I' m tring to deploy Uniswap V3 subgraph to a local graph node that is connected to a local ethereum node on the goerli network.**

The **OS** is xubuntu v21.10 .
The **node** is hyperledger besu v22.1.2.
The **graph-node** version is 0.26.0 and run with docker-compose .

**In the subgraph.yaml i have removed this:**
graft:
base:
block:

Because i haven't this subgraph deployed local, i changed the network to goerli and the start block to '7011478'.
For the deploy I use these commands:

```
yarn
yarn codegen
yarn create-local
yarn deploy-local
```

After deployment and after some blocks have been indexed I get this **error**:

ERROR:

```
 Handler skipped due to execution failure, error: Mapping aborted at ~**lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/index.ts**, line 811, column 4, with message: **Value is not a BigInt**. wasm backtrace:        0: 0x25f8 - <unknown>!**src/types/schema/Token#get:decimals**       1: 0x2611 - <unknown>!~**lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/index/BigDecimal#constructor**     2: 0x29e3 - <unknown>!src/mappings/
**position-manager/handleDecreaseLiquidity**    , **handler: handleIncreaseLiquidity**, block_hash: 0x41ea414f5ef6ef940b2b0557d0f403f8b2c1c32c22616dd4d45e0cf3a81dc8d0, block_number: 7011552, sgd: 1, subgraph_id: 
QmNwsfk3kJi8zzmBDVEiCGqioRnpyZM1iSTPPVYVNyDsop, component: SubgraphInstanceManager
```

**Does anyone have any idea what it could be?**

Comment: It looks like you are trying to deploy a Uniswap V3 Subgraph , can you please show the subgraph yaml file ?  and reveal more details in which chain(layer)  you trying to deploy subgraph.

Comment: Hi, I tried to deploy it on the goerli testnet. I downloaded the subgraph from github, the subgraph.yaml is this: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-subgraph/blob/main/subgraph.yaml . I removed the lines 6, 7, 8:                                  #graft:
#  base: QmPrb5mvZj3ycUugZgwLWCvK93jfXfhvfjRXrFk4tRmyCX
#  block: 14292820                                                                                                                  I changed the network from 'mainnet' to 'goerli' , and the startBlock to 7011478      If you need more details just let me know. Thank you for your support